# boost lexical cast double to string giving invalid results

Tags: c++, boost, double, precision, boost-lexicalcast

I am trying this:

```
std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(0.0009) << std::endl;
```

and expecting the output to be:

```
0.0009
```

But the output is:

```
0.00089999999999999998
```

g++ version:  5.4.0, Boost version: 1.66

What can I do to make it print what it's been given.

Comment: That isn't an invalid result from the cast, just more precise than you wanted. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @chris I thought so. Seems like there are no ways to mitigate it as per that answer. I just need to print it as it is (as 0.0009).

Comment: @AbbasFaisal there is a way, just not with binary floating point types. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** in fact override the default precision:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47dfc103c7d182d4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#ifdef BOOST_LCAST_NO_COMPILE_TIME_PRECISION
#    error unsupported
#endif

template <> struct boost::detail::lcast_precision<double> : std::integral_constant<unsigned, 5> { };

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(0.0009) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
0.0009
```

However, this is both not supported (`detail::`) and not flexible (all doubles will come out this way now).

### The Real Problem

The problem is loss of accuracy converting from the decimal representation to the binary representation. Instead, use a decimal float representation:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93865f248305e39a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using Double = boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;

int main() {
    Double x("0.009"),
           y = x*2,
           z = x/77;

    for (Double v : { x, y, z }) {
        std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(v) << "\n";
        std::cout << v << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
0.009
0.009
0.018
0.018
0.000116883
0.000116883
```

Answer (score 3):

`boost::lexical_cast` doesn't allow you to specify the precision when converting a floating point number into its string representation. From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

> For more involved conversions, such as where precision or formatting need tighter control than is offered by the default behavior of `lexical_cast`, the conventional `std::stringstream` approach is recommended.

So you could use `stringstream`

```
double d = 0.0009;
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setprecision(4) << d;
std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
```

Or another option is to use the [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/doc/format.html) library.

```
std::string s = (boost::format("%1$.4f") % d).str();
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

[Both will print `0.0009`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17a1ec0559409154)

Comment: You can [cheat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48598500/85371), but the real problem is the assumption that `0.0009` is somehow binary exact. (Addressed in my answer as well)

Comment: @sehe Yes, absolutely agree. +1 to you, I didn't know about `cpp_dec_float_50`.

Answer (score 2):

`0.0009` is a double precision floating literal with, assuming IEEE754, the value

```
0.00089999999999999997536692664112933925935067236423492431640625
```

That's what `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>` sees as the function parameter. And the default precision setting in the `cout` formatter is rounding to the 17th significant figure:

```
0.00089999999999999998
```

Really, if you want exact *decimal* precision, then use a decimal type (Boost has one), or work in integers and splice in the decimal separator yourself. But in your case, given that you're simply outputting the number with no complex calculations, rounding to the 15th significant figure will have the desired effect: inject

```
std::setprecision(15)
```

into the output stream.

Comment: Just a quick question: Is the decimal type cpp_dec_float_50/cpp_dec_float_100 you are referring to?